# Unable to locate css file of button in wordpress inspect element

Tags: wordpress

When I'm trying to edit the button style in word press theme, I am unable to locate the CSS path in cpanel directory.

When I am using inspect element, it shows the following CSS url:-

http://www.chivazo.com/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/jackbox/css/jackbox.min.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/colorpicker/colorpicker.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/style.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/css/responsive.css,wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-woocart-popup-lite/static/styles/frontend/style.css

I'm getting confused about how to find the right CSS path.

Please help me.

page URL:- http://www.chivazo.com/checkout/

Comment: just delete cache of bwp plugin and deactivate it.... they inspect button.. you will find correct css file, edit it and then you can activate the BWP plugin again.

Answer (score -1):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='brands-styles-group-css' href='http://www.chivazo.com/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-brands/assets/css/style.css,wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-currency-converter-widget/assets/css/converter.css,wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-product-filter-premium/assets/css/frontend.css,wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search/assets/css/yith_wcas_ajax_search.css,wp-content/plugins/yith-infinite-scrolling/assets/css/frontend.css,wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-compare/assets/css/colorbox.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/css/bootstrap.min.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/css/theme-animate.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jackbox-group-css' href='http://www.chivazo.com/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/jackbox/css/jackbox.min.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/plugins/colorpicker/colorpicker.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/style.css,wp-content/themes/chivazo/css/responsive.css,wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-woocart-popup-lite/static/styles/frontend/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom-style-css'  href='http://www.chivazo.com/wp-content/themes/chivazo/css/custom_style.php' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

You have this format for calling stylesheets so that every thing came in a single line. Keep separate lines.

Please check your viewpage source.

Comment: That's normal behaviour, this is how BWP works: it call a PHP script passing in GET parameters the css files to minify.